# Configuring IIS7 Host Headers -- Redirect

Tags: windows, http, iis, https, iis-7

I'm currently having some issues with configuring host headers using IIS 7.5 (w2008r2).

The bindings/configurations are as follows:

siteA

http www.sitea.com port 80
https port 443 --- the certificate used is issued for www.sitea.com

A rewrite rule to redirect all attempts to connect over http to https.

siteB

http dev.sitea.com port 80

The A record for dev.sitea.com currently resolves to the server's IP, as expected.

The issue is that when you attempt to connect to dev.sitea.com, it redirects you to www.sitea.com.

Removing the rewrite rule and https binding from the config for siteA had no effect.

I'm unsure of where to go from here to continue troubleshooting. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question, If you stop www.sitea.com, does dev.sitea.com come up?

If not, then you have an incorrect binding.

Make sure that for dev.sitea.com you have a binding set to the same IP address.

Also make sure you don't have the same line in your web.config of dev.sitea.com to redirect to the https://www.sitea.com

Comment: Also, make sure you have the **Host Name** setup for both domains. I just ran a quick test scenario on my Win2008 box and verified that this should all work.

Comment: It turns out there was a redirect on the default index page that was pulling a stale database setting and redirecting all traffic to www.siteA.com. Thanks!